# Heroku "Process exited with status 137" node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I recently posted a question on a similar topic. I did a major overhaul of everything on the URL, and the same thing happened as last time: I could deploy everything and run it using `heroku local web`. When I went to the web dyno, it said I had an application error and I then check the logs. Here is what it said (I am using a project on github called atwork):

```
2017-05-02T02:35:39.191493+00:00 app[web.1]: Loaded model: chats.js
2017-05-02T02:35:39.200517+00:00 app[web.1]: Loaded model: streams.js
2017-05-02T02:35:39.196830+00:00 app[web.1]: Loaded model: posts.js
2017-05-02T02:35:39.209761+00:00 app[web.1]: Loaded model: users.js
2017-05-02T02:35:40.067321+00:00 app[web.1]: AtWork running at http://:::8111
2017-05-02T02:35:50.116492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=room111-thoughts.herokuapp.com request_id=44a6e779-e6b8-4a33-a5b9-53430af2ad8f fwd="108.221.62.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-02T02:36:35.859814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-05-02T02:36:35.859903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-05-02T02:36:35.956564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-05-02T02:36:35.969766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-02T02:37:22.933285+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=room111-thoughts.herokuapp.com request_id=80ffc71f-d792-4538-b50a-5140b7658819 fwd="108.221.62.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am a beginner to Heroku and Node.js, so any help is appreciated. I will provide any information needed to find an answer.

Comment: For me, it was npm packages installed globally on my machine that weren't explicit in package.json. Thus in heroku the require line would fail

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I checked the logs, it said that `at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"`, it means you have `uncaught Exception`, so you should check your code.

if you want to use `mongodb` on Heroku, you should try to add the `mongodb addon` for your application. you can find the doc [here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongohq)

and try to use `process.env.PORT`, not the port you want to use.

if it doesn't still solve your problem, you can try to use this command `heroku run bash`, this command can make you into heroku environment and start your server.

Comment: Yeah, it's really odd because everything runs as planned when I use `heroku run bash` and run `npm start`... it's just for web dynos. Should I try something else?

Comment: it seems that there is some problem about the Port you use: `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`. try to use `process.env.PORT`.

Comment: using process.env.PORT instead of hardcoding the port fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm using Gatsby and Heroku and everything was working and deploying OK. But now that it's in production I cannot build an app even when I change nothing (except one space so I can do `git push heroku master`)

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error upon hosting a Node app on heroku turn out it was the port problem so just do this set the port equal to this

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

> So process.env.PORT || 8080 means: whatever is in the environment variable PORT, or 8080 if there's nothing there.

And then set the set port variable in the following

```
var server=app.listen(port,function() {
console.log("app running on port 8080"); });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a port issue. Just use something like this:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3002
```

to specify your port.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app is timing out before it actually starts the server:

> App boot timeout

Could the process be taking too long to minify production assets?

Comment: If that was the case, how do you set your environment to hold longer?